# How to match key from index replace it with the value from the key?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, key

I just started learning python so I don't know even the most basic functions, what should I do if I want to match the key `"user"` from dict to JSON display and print it as member with the new value on the dict in python?

```
id = {"user":"member", "ex":"ex"} #my dictionary
messages:{"user":{"updatedat":int, "createdat":int}} #JSON
print messages.get(dict.keys(id)) #< I'm not doing this part right
```

Comment: You can use the `json` module in Python's standard library to convert JSON objects into Python dictionaries (and vice-versa). If you do that, then you can manipulate the data just like any other dictionary, and when you're done you can convert it back into JSON format.

Comment: Try using [JSON.loads()](https://www.adamsmith.haus/python/answers/how-to-extract-a-value-from-json-in-python) to convert the json into a dictionary and grab the values needed then use [update()](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary-update-method/amp/) to update the values of your dictionary.

Comment: @martineau is there anyway can do it without having to convert it

Comment: @AliasCartellano is there anyway i can do it without having to convert the json

Comment: There's no way that's less work or code.